# Как избежать отказа в обслуживании при замене SSL-сертификата?

Tags: администрирование, ssl, https, поддомены

У меня есть сайт на домене `my.site` <sup>(вымышленное название)</sup>

У меня есть действительный сертификат на него.

Мне понадобился **wildcard** сертификат `*.my.site` (Т.е. распространяющийся на все поддомены моего домена)

Я заказал его через другого посредника у другого центра регистрации.

После оплаты, как только я подтвердил владение доменом, посредник выпустил мне сертификат. Но проблема в том, что старый сертификат установленный на `my.site` тут же перестал быть действительным. А это соответственно привело к небольшому простою сайта. Как-то можно этого избежать? Возможно посредник как-то не так подал заявку? Я вообще наивно полагал, что старый сертификат будет действителен до окончания срока действия.

Comment: Что-то подозрительно. Тем более, что мне казалось, что `*.my.site` в принципе не подойдёт для `my.site`.

Comment: Старый должен остаться действительным. Пинайте посредника, возможно, он перестарался. Ну или вообще используйте LE, они выдают wildcard бесплатно и без вот таких сюрпризов

Comment: @Qwertiy в сертификате в дополнительных именах субъекта указан и my.site

Comment: @PashaPash вину отрицают, валят всё на посредника выдавшего старый сертификат

Comment: @4per врут. посреднику, который выдал старый сертификат, все равно. Старому центру сертификации - тоже. Чтобы старый сертификат перестал работать - при заказе нового кто-то должен быть попросить старый центр сертификации отозвать сертификат. Если принципиально - можно написать им и спросить, на каком основании отозвали. Стандартного протокола нет, по спеке - An authorized person advises a CA of an abnormal situation requiring certificate revocation. Напишите CA, скажите что вы никого не авторизовали на отзыв, и сами не отправляли запрос, мол, беспредел.

Comment: @4per единственный раз, когда я вообще видел отзыв сертификата - это когда у нас протеряли приватный ключ, и попросили CA перевыпустить сертификат. Тогда отозвали одновременно с выпуском нового. Но это был явный запрос, а не просто перевыпуск кем-то еще.

Comment: Вы правы - пока сертификат не истёк и не отозван, он валиден. https://serverfault.com/questions/590504/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificates-have-been-revoked -- как проверить статус отзыва сертификата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard должен включать в себя и сам домен и субдомены, вот мой [тестовый хост](https://aepot.ru/) с Wildcard сертификатом Let's Encypt, посмотрите сертификат. Если включены только субдомены, а сам домен не включен, значит вы неправильно заказали сертификат, или вам неправильно его оформили.

Вот такие поля должны быть в Wildcard сертификате при просмотре в браузере:

| Дополнительное имя субъекта |  |
| --- | --- |
| DNS-имя | *.my.site |
| DNS-имя | my.site |

Либо с помощью командной строки

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text
```

Вот такое должно быть в выводе

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:*.my.site, DNS:my.site
```

> Как-то можно этого избежать?

Проверять сертификат перед установкой, что он содержит в себе все нужные домены, поддомены, и у него корректные даты истечения. Можно автотест написать, который будет валидировать полученный сертификат.

---

А то что старый отозвали, это нонсенс. В нормальной ситуации вы можете хоть 100500 одновременно действующих сертификатов иметь на домен и субдомены без каких-либо ограничений. Я не знаю, как по-другому ответить на ваш вопрос, в этом случае его надо центру сертификации задавать, а в случае материального ущерба - в судебном порядке. Этот случай за рамками ответственности сисадмина.

Comment: писал в комментариях, в дополнительных именах субъекта всё есть. И новый сертификат работает, не работает старый

Comment: @4per дополнил ответ

Comment: Проблема в непредвиденном даун-тайме

Comment: @4per ну, даже у гугла бывают даунтаймы. В рамках нормы даунтайм или нет, надо смотреть в [SLA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3) сервиса. Урегулирование нарушений условий SLA - уже юридическая сторона вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Техподдержка центра сертификации ответила, что у них был инцидент и пострадало много сертификатов. Ну т.е. якобы это было просто совпадение.

Сказали, чтобы я перевыпустил сертификат через посредника. Я перевыпустил, но устанавливать не стал, т.к. он мне уже не нужен. Если кому интересно, поможет или нет, могу проверить.

> Как избежать?

Не ясно.